# How can I pass NO to for a particular upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, apt, upgrade

I am running the following commands:

```
1. sudo apt-get update --fix-missing 
2. sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Now when I am doing the 2nd one, it tells me at a certain point later in installation:

```
Setting up openjdk-6-jre-headless (6b40-1.13.12-0ubuntu0.12.04.1) ...

Configuration file `/etc/java-6-openjdk/security/java.security'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** java.security (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

I want to pass N for only such cases. How can I pass this flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `--assume-no` parameters in `apt-get`.

Try something like

```
sudo apt-get --assume-no upgrade <package-name>
```

**Details:**

The [manual page of apt-get](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get) (You can also refer to manual page with `man apt-get` command) mentions:

> **--assume-no**
>
> Automatic "no" to all prompts. Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-No.

Contrary to this parameter, you also have

> **-y, --yes, --assume-yes**
>
> Automatic yes to prompts. Assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as
> changing a held package or removing an essential package, occurs then
> apt-get will abort.  Configuration Item: APT::Get::Assume-Yes.

Answer (score 0):

use `--assume-no` parameter in such cases.